# Stateful Batch Apex with logic outside of the execute() method

Tags: apex, batch, stateful

I'm not even sure how to ask this question, but here goes:

I have Batch class that needs to maintain state. The class looks something like this:

```
global class myBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful {

    global id[] AppliedChanges;

    global database.Querylocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator(accountsQuery);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, Account[] scope){
        myBatch.doWork(scope);
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){
        //do something with AppliedChanges
    }

    public static void doWork(){
        AppliedChanges = AppliedChanges == null ? new id[]{} : AppliedChanges;
        //Do tons of work, eventually populate add to AppliedChanges
    }
}
```

In `doWork()`, I can debug `AppledChanges` and see that it has values but, in the `finish()` method, `AppliedChanges` is always null.

The `doWork()` method exists so I can use that logic elsewhere in Salesforce without having to run a batch.

How can I populate `AppliedChanges` in the `doWork()` method and then use it in `finish()`?

Comment: additionally, unless you're exposing outside of a package namespace the batch methods should probably just be `public` though the doc examples usually use the `global` modifier. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_access_modifiers.htm "use `global` rarely, if at all"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `static` keyword. It basically means "stateless", which is the opposite of what you want.

**Works**

```
public void doWork()
```

**Fails**

```
public static void doWork()
```

Comment: Sigh... I knew it was something like that. I ended up having two change `doWork()` to `doWorkInternal()`, then add a new method for `doWork()` like:

`public static doWork(){
    myBatch.doWorkInternal();
}`

Seems to work. Apologies for the weird comment formatting

Thanks!!